# Seeking a (simple-to-use) solution for communication over 12V DC power lines

Tags: dc, communication, power-line-communication

I am working on a project that involves communication over a 12V DC (2A) power line using a two-wire cable. I would like to transmit data over the same cable and am looking for a simple-to-use IC or solution that can handle communication over 12V DC power lines.

Ideally, I am looking for a dedicated DC power line communication solution that is easy to implement with an STM32 microcontroller. My communication requirements are relatively slow, and I don't need a high data rate (30 bytes/s would be fine).

I am aware of chips like the MAX485 (RS-485 transceiver) and Yamar Electronics SIG60 (DC-BUS transceiver), but the MAX485 is not specifically designed for DC power lines and would thus require a fair bit of extra components. The Yamar Electronics SIG60, on the other hand, is not readily available (but does seem to fit the bill).

Can anyone recommend a suitable solution for this application? It seems like this would be something for which ready-made integrated solutions exist but I can't seem to find them.

Any suggestions or guidance (perhaps another type of approach?) would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with the 1-wire communications protocol?

Answer (score 4):

> *My communication requirements are relatively slow, and I don't need a
> high data rate*

Slow data rate isn't going to actually help because...

...We always modify the BW of the data so that it doesn't have DC components (it's called non-return-to-zero or NRZ). Then we can easily interface NRZ to DC because its spectral content is DC free. We do this with an inductor and a capacitor. The inductor feeds the DC onto the line and, the capacitor feeds the data onto the line.

It's the same story at the "other end" of the line; we use an inductor to extract the DC and, a capacitor to extract the NRZ data: -

[image]

Image taken from my answer on the subject of [data over a 5V DC power connector](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/123943/20218). Another name is phantom power (as used by microphone audio signals but, in our case, it's used by data).

So, if your data rate is low, I suggest you Manchester encode it or, mix it with a carrier of higher frequency. There are other ways of course but these are common methods for producing NRZ data.

The information above is [largely supported by a guy from TI (written 12 years ago)](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface-group/interface/f/interface-forum/75687/data-over-dc-power-line-using-rs485-2-wire): -

[image]

He mentions using common-mode chokes but, really, they are common mode chokes being used differentially (note the dots on the chokes). Note also that an RS485 chip is used at both ends but, of course, the data is specified as being Manchester encoded.

> *Can anyone recommend a suitable IC for this application? It seems like
> this would be something for which ready-made integrated solutions
> exist but I can't seem to find them.*

Chip recommendation requests for these are off-topic but, as it happens, I also know of none. However, you should remove these requests from your question to avoid it being closed.

Comment: It is common to send a "RF" carrier down the power line.  100khz, 120khz, 455khz are common. "X-10" systems use 120khz.  This way the inductors can be much smaller, and you don't need Manchester.

Comment: @ronsimpson quite correct.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't take much. There needs to be an AC choke on both ends of the line so that the AC doesn't get shorted to ground.

The transmit side can be a capacitively-coupled output from a UART pin set to high drive current. The UART needs to drive DC-balanced data out, so the number of zeroes and ones in every byte needs to match. The start and stop bits balance each other so won't be a problem. With an external inverter, the data can be driven differentially. Without it, the data goes single-ended onto the (+) wire.

You won't be sending raw data bytes directly out the UART, but first encode them into a couple of DC-balanced symbols, and transmit those out instead.

On the receiver side, a high-pass filter, a bit of gain, and a comparator, should be most that's needed to get the data back out. The gain doesn't even need to be fancy: a BJT AC amplifier is plenty enough. That's for single-ended transmission. For differential transmission, an op-amp will do fine as an amplifier - it doesn't need to be a differential amplifier, since the comparator can compare relative to the common mode.

Comment: The gaps between bytes (normally high) are going to cause the system you describe a real problem. NRZ data needs to be sent over an AC link.

Comment: @Andyaka Why should that be a problem? Just set the UART to perhaps 115200 Baud and pick two byte constants representing a 1 and 0 bit (say, 0xAA and 0x55 for "PSK"-like or 0xAA and 0x33 for "FSK"-like operation, on top of that 115.2 kHz "carrier"). Any other received bytes are silently discarded. AC-couple the receiver and bias its amplifier so that it outputs high unless told otherwise. Add pauses between transmitted bytes, checksums, framing, or FEC to taste.